# select max(date) for each group SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this :

```
QUOTE_ID   CREATED_DATE  CHARGE_1 CHARGE_2
2    2018-06-11 19:51:10.0    00   16
2    2017-06-11 19:51:10.0    01   16
3    2017-06-11 19:51:10.0    10   16
4    2019-06-11 19:51:10.0    20   16
4    2020-06-11 19:51:10.0    02   16
4    2017-06-11 19:51:10.0    00   16
```

i would like to select only per each QUOTE_ID the row which has the MAXimum CREATED_DATE.

So the result should be like this :

```
QUOTE_ID   CREATED_DATE  CHARGE_1 CHARGE_2
2    2018-06-11 19:51:10.0    00   16
3    2017-06-11 19:51:10.0    10   16
4    2020-06-11 19:51:10.0    02   16
```

I tryed with this SQL code (with ORACLE )

```
SELECT tt.*
FROM CUSTOM_LIFETIME_VALUE_LOY_JOIN tt
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT "QUOTE_ID", MAX("CREATED_DATE") AS MaxDateTime
    FROM CUSTOM_LIFETIME_VALUE_LOY_JOIN
    GROUP BY QUOTE_ID) groupedtt 
ON tt.QUOTE_ID = groupedtt.QUOTE_ID 
AND tt.CREATED_DATE = groupedtt.MaxDateTime
```

But it seems no correct since i didnt get all the QUOTE_ID rows

Any idea please to help me to resolve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical way is to use `row_number()`:

```
select clv.*
from (select clv.*,
             row_number() over (partition by quote_id order by created_date desc) as seqnum
      from CUSTOM_LIFETIME_VALUE_LOY_JOIN clv
     ) clv
where seqnum = 1;
```

Note that your version should work as well -- except when `quote_id` is `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this SQL code (with ORACLE )

```
SELECT tt.*
FROM CUSTOM_LIFETIME_VALUE_LOY_JOIN tt
WHERE (tt.QUOTE_ID,tt.CREATED_DATE) IN 
      (SELECT QUOTE_ID, MAX("CREATED_DATE") AS MaxDateTime
     FROM CUSTOM_LIFETIME_VALUE_LOY_JOIN
     GROUP BY QUOTE_ID)
```